# Como fazer calculos com elementos de um array em Ruby?

Tags: array, ruby

```
    numeros = [1, 2]

class C
    def calcule_array(*numeros)
      puts a + b
    end

  end

  numeros = C.new

  puts numeros
```

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer cálculos com elementos inteiros que estão dentro de um array em Ruby, tentei o código acima mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pontos importantes:

- Remova o operador `splat` que esta antes do nome do parâmetro `*numeros`
- Você esta redeclarando a variável `numeros` quando instancia a classe `C`

depois você pode utilizar o método [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) ou [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4]

class C
  def calcule_array(numeros)
    puts numeros.reduce(:+)
  end
end

calcular = C.new
calcular.calcule_array(numeros)
```

Saída:

```
> 10
```

*Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/pt-stackoverflow-341030)*